# Lemma regarding density function

Tags: probability

**Lemma**:  Let **Z** be an n-dimensional continuous random variable. If, for every $B \subset \mathbb{R}^n$, 
\begin{equation}
P(\textbf{Z} \in B)=\int_B h(\textbf{x}) d\textbf{x}
\end{equation}
then $h$ is the density of **Z**.

---

This lemma is in my textbook and it was stated without proof and I wonder if anyone can refer me to a proof of it. Perhaps it is trivially easy to prove but I haven't figured it out yet.

My difficulty in proving it lies in that we are dealing with $\textbf Z \in B$ where $B$ is an arbitrary subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and not $[a_1,b_1]\times...\times[a_n,b_n]$.

Comment: Isn't this just the definition of a density? See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function#Formal_definition

Comment: Hm... My book doesn't define probability density function with measure theory, but simply as the derivate of the cumulative distribution function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $F(x_1,...,x_n) = P[Z_1 \leq x_1, \ldots, Z_n \leq x_n]$ be the cumulative distribution function. Since $h$ satisfies the relationship you specified, this means that for 
$B = (-\infty,x_1]\times \cdots \times (-\infty,x_n]$, 
$$
  F(x_1,\ldots,x_n)
= \int_B h(t) dt.
$$
This is the multidimensional analogue of what you learned for one dimensional densities.

Comment: But $B$ isn't necessarily $B=(-\inf,x_1]\times \dots \times (-\inf,x_n]$? It could be any subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: According to your definition, the relation holds for all $B$, and so that one in particular, so it follows from what you have that $F$ defined above has $h$ as its density.

Comment: Ah, of course, thanks!